# How to define style for disabled button using Material Design with AppCompat?

Tags: android, material-design, android-drawable, android-appcompat, android-styles

I am trying to set a disabled look to a button via

```
Button.setBackgroundResource(Drawable);
```

but I am struggling with the definition.

Comment: Use Button.setEnabled(false) and Button.getBackground().setAlpha(100) to give a disabled look to a button.

Comment: It seems like a little "sloppy" solution ;)